# Multiple inputs on one line

Tags: c++, input, cin

I have looked to no avail, and I'm afraid that it might be such a simple question that nobody dares ask it.

Can one input multiple things from standard input in one line? I mean this:

```
float a, b;
char c;

// It is safe to assume a, b, c will be in float, float, char form?
cin >> a >> b >> c;
```

Comment: Some questions don't need to be asked. What happens when you try it?

Comment: I am not currently in a place where I have the means to try this.

Comment: @Joshua You don't have [internet](http://ideone.com/) [access](http://codepad.org/)?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes, you can input multiple items from `cin`, using exactly the syntax you describe. The result is essentially identical to:

```
cin >> a;
cin >> b;
cin >> c;
```

This is due to a technique called "operator chaining".

Each call to `operator>>(istream&, T)` (where `T` is some arbitrary type) returns a reference to its first argument.  So `cin >> a` returns `cin`, which can be used as `(cin>>a)>>b` and so forth.

Note that each call to `operator>>(istream&, T)` first consumes all whitespace characters, then as many characters as is required to satisfy the input operation, up to (but not including) the first next whitespace character, invalid character, or EOF.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking so, but I couldn't really test it where I am, and I was itching for knowledge.

Comment: I was aware of the leading whitespace thing, but not the rest. Neat!

Comment: Note that whitespace characters will only be consumed if the `skipws` flag is set.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can.

From [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/operator%3E%3E/):

> Because these functions are operator overloading functions, the usual way in which they are called is:
>
> ```
>    strm >> variable;
> ```
>
> Where `strm` is the identifier of a istream object and `variable` is an object of any type supported as right parameter. It is also possible to call a succession of extraction operations as:
>
> ```
>    strm >> variable1 >> variable2 >> variable3; //...
> ```
>
> which is the same as performing successive extractions from the same object `strm`.

Just replace `strm` with `cin`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is absolutely right to consider that variables a, b, and c are within the float, float, and char data types - just as specified.

To make it easier to read, I would suggest adding some space between the variables, in the output (`cout<<`).

For example, you could try something like this: `cout<<"The alphanumeric elements entered are as follows: "<< a << " " << b << " " << c <<endl;`

As far as inputting multiple items on a single line: yes, it is absolutely possible.

All of the below three can work:

```html
cin >> a; 
cin >> b; 
cin >> c;
```

```html
cin >> a >> b >> c ;
```

```html
cin >> a ; cin >> b ; cin >> c ;
```