# C++: Expression must be a modifiable lvalue

Tags: c++, math, trigonometry, math.h, cmath

I am making a text based simple operation/trig calculator. I am getting the error: "Expression must be a modifiable lvalue" when I attempt to sqrt the squared variables. Here is my current code: (the error highlights the sqrt)

```
double a, b, result;

cout << "Please enter your two side lengths (ex:12 5)";
cin >> a, b;
sqrt(pow(a, 2) + pow(b, 2)) = result;

cout << result << endl;
```

Apologies for any formatting errors, first question asked here any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: try `result = sqrt(....);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `cin` statement to `cin >> a >> b;`, this reads multiple values at once, since the comma operator doesn't exist for `cin`. Also, switch the order of the result variable on the right side of the assignment to left side. The two operands to the `=` on the assignment are l-values, standing for left-values, supposed to be on the left side, and r-values, standing for right-values, supposed to be on the right side. Switch them, and you get an error.

#### Your new Modified Code

```
double a, b, result;

cout << "Please enter your two side lengths (ex:12 5)";

cin >> a >> b; //<-- See '>>' here

//sqrt(pow(a, 2) + pow(b, 2)) = result; <-- switch these to...

result = sqrt(pow(a, 2) + pow(b, 2)); //<-- ...this
cout << result << endl;
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://cpp.sh/2f4d2)</kbd>

Comment: [The comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). : )

Comment: Ah yes, I did this in other parts of my program but missed that here. Thanks for solving an error before I knew I had it!

Comment: Ah, well, i know the comma operator there, but not otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

First, `cin >> a, b` [does not do what you think it's doing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7425318/4354477). You'd better write `cin >> a >> b`.

Then, you assign *data* to variables, not *variables* to data. So do `result = sqrt(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

You've switched around your assignment.  You're trying to assign the sqrt function the value of result; you want to assign the result to the value of the sqrt output:

```
double a, b, result;

cout << "Please enter your two side lengths (ex:12 5)";
cin >> a, b;
result = sqrt(pow(a, 2) + pow(b, 2));

cout << result << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is the line number `4` and `5` of your piece of code.

`cin >> a,b;` is wrong. You can take multiple input in a line like this `cin >> a >> b;`

And in the line number 5 you are doing assignment in wrong order. You should just reverse it `result` this way `result = sqrt(pow(a, 2) + pow(b, 2)) ;`