# how do I store month, day and year in 3 separate variables from the same input? (C++). it needs to be in MM / DD / YYYY with spaces between the /

Tags: c++, cin

```
int month, day, year;
cout << "Enter your date of birth" << endl;
cout << "format: month / day / year  -->" << endl;
cin >> month;
cin >> day;
cin >> year;
```

it needs to be in MM / DD / YYYY with spaces between the /.

Comment: Use `scanf` to do this.

Comment: hi, im new to c++ do you mind sharing an example code please? thank you so much.

Comment: probably simplest just to read the slashes into a char variable (and probably check that what was read was actually a slash)

Comment: @i486 `scanf` is a C function, not a C++ one.

Comment: @i486 Why? The OP decorated this question with the C++ and `cin` tag.

Comment: @fudo `scanf` works with C++ without any problem. Do you know it?

Comment: @i486 of course, but he explicitly asked for a C++ solution

Answer (score 2):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425318/multiple-inputs-on-one-line) on a similar question, you can't `cin` multiple variables in a single shot, but you should be able to chain multiple `cin`, type in a single input and have each `cin` get its own value from standard input.

**NOT TESTED**

```cpp
int year, month, day;
char slash;

// example input: 2022 / 10 / 12
cin >> year >> slash >> month >> slash >> day;
```

Comment: [Tested](https://godbolt.org/z/TbGcPP6Mr).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strptime` to parse time from input. For example.

```
struct tm t {0};
std::string input;
std::cin >> input;
if (strptime(input.c_str(), "%m/%d/%Y", &t)){
    int d = t.tm_mday;
    int m = t.tm_mon + 1;
    int y = t.tm_year + 1900;
} else {
    std::cout << "invalid date format\n";
}
```